# Avoid user to scroll to index -1 and 2 with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController with 2 VCs (index 0 and 1) and I want to avoid the user to scroll to the right on the first view (index 0) and to scroll to the left on the second view (index 1).

Is there anybody who can tell me how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: not clear what you are trying to achieve. please elaborate..

Comment: @iProgrammer I have 2 views on the pageViewController. I want that if the user is on the 1st view, he won't be able to swipe to the right (just to the left - to the 2nd view), and if he's on the 2nd view he won't be able to swipe to the left (just to the right - to the 1st view). Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Try these datasource methods:

**@SWIFT Version**

```
public func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = viewControllers.indexOf(viewController)
    if index == 0 || index == NSNotFound {
        return nil
    }

    index--
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

public func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = viewControllers.indexOf(viewController)
    if index == NSNotFound {
        return nil
    }

    index++
    if index == viewControllers?.count {
        return nil
    }

    return viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}
```

**@OBJC Version**

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = [viewControllerArray indexOfObject:viewController];

    if ((index == NSNotFound) || (index == 0)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = [viewControllerArray indexOfObject:viewController];

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }
    index++;

    if (index == [viewControllerArray count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: The user is till able to scroll, it just shows a black view on the sides, I don't want the black view, I want it to not be scrollable for this side

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Index value of UIPageViewcontroller to achieve this. But this is quite painful... let you check it.